# Get all <div> siblings until next <div> with a specific text with lxml.thml and XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I have an HTML file that would have the contents like this:

```
<div>File: NameFile1</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>
<div>File: NameFile2</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>
```

So I would need to get an XPath expression to get all the text div of every file

I have written the following

```
from lxml import html
h = '''
<div>File: NameFile1</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>
<div>File: NameFile2</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>'''
tree = html.fromstring(h)
files_div = tree.xpath(r"//div[contains(text(),'File:'")
files = dict()
for file_div in files_div:
    files[file_div] = file_div.xpath(r".following_sibling[not(contains(text(),'File')) and contains(text(),'Text')])
```

However, using the previous XPath expression it gets me all the text of all files, and I only want to get the text for the matching file. How would be the XPath expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for a problem like this.

A solution would then be:

```
h = '''
<div>File: NameFile1</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>
<div>File: NameFile2</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

files = {}
x = soup.find('div')
current_file = ''
while True:
    if 'File:' in x.text:
        current_file = x.text
        files[current_file] = []
    else:
        files[current_file].append(x.text)

    x = x.find_next_sibling('div')
    if x is None:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/*/div[contains(text(), 'File:')][1]/following-sibling::div[contains(text(), 'Text')  and count(preceding-sibling::div[contains(text(), 'File:')])=1]
```

This XPath selects all DIV elements containing the word `Text` following the first element containing `File:`.

For the second file use

```
/*/div[contains(text(), 'File:')][2]/following-sibling::div[contains(text(), 'Text')  and count(preceding-sibling::div[contains(text(), 'File:')])=2]
```

and so on.
Therefore loop over the number of elements containing `File:`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough with bs4 4.7.1 to use :contains to do the filtering

If you want entire tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div>File: NameFile1</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>
<div>File: NameFile2</div>
<div>Text1: some text</div>
<div>Text2: another text</div>
<div>Text3: another text</div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
search_term = 'File: '
files_div = [i.text.replace(search_term,'') for i in soup.select(f'div:contains("{search_term}")')]
files = dict()

for number, file_div in enumerate(files_div):
    if file_div != files_div[-1]:
        files[file_div] = soup.select(f'div:contains("{file_div}"), div:contains("{file_div}") ~ div:not(div:contains("' + files_div[number+1] + '"), div:contains("' + files_div[number+1] + '") ~ div)')
    else:
        files[file_div] = soup.select(f'div:contains("{file_div}"),div:contains("{file_div}") ~ div')

print(files)
```

If you want just `.text` of each tag

```
for number, file_div in enumerate(files_div):
    if file_div != files_div[-1]:
        files[file_div] = [i.text for i in soup.select(f'div:contains("{file_div}"), div:contains("{file_div}") ~ div:not(div:contains("' + files_div[number+1] + '"), div:contains("' + files_div[number+1] + '") ~ div)')]
    else:
        files[file_div] = [i.text for i in soup.select(f'div:contains("{file_div}"),div:contains("{file_div}") ~ div')]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` with `str.split`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
r = [b for _, b in map(lambda x:x.text.split(': '), soup(d, 'html.parser').find_all('div'))]
```

Output:

```
['NameFile1', 'some text', 'another text', 'another text', 'NameFile2', 'some text', 'another text', 'another text']
```